# Solve $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x}\right)^x}$ without l’Hôpital

Tags: real-analysis, limits-without-lhopital

I am trying to solve a high school exercise dealing with limits.

The limit I need to solve is
$$l=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x}\right)^x}.$$

Which can be solved as follows:
$$l=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}{e^{\ln{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1+x^2}}{|x|}\right)^x}}}= \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}{e^{x\ln{\left(1+\sqrt{1+x^2}\right)}-x\ln{|x|}}}.$$

Since $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}x\ln{x}=0$, then $l=1$.

Now, at this stage in the high school book the derivatives are not yet explained. Hence, no l’Hôpital theorem. Even reasonings about infinities are explained in the next chapter.

So, is there a way to solve the limit without using the $x\ln x$ limit, only by means of basic known limits?

Comment: Probably want a right-handed limit $x\to 0^+,$ since the term inside the exponent is negative when $x<0,$ and $a^x$ is undefined when $a<0.$

Comment: Knowing $x^x\to 1$ as $x\to0^+$ means the numerator and denominator both converge to $1,$ so this is not an indeterminate form. ($x^x$ **is** an indeterminate form, so you will have to show that converges to $1.$